Make borders in dataframe pandas
How to make borders in dataframe in each cell:

For example I have got the following dataframe:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'planet': ['Earth', 'Moon', 'Mars'], 'mass_to_earth': [1, 0.606, 0.107]})

df

And I need to get bold (and not) borders in this table in each cell. How can I do this?

Here is some information on table visualition

Assuming you are using Jupyter even though you don't mention that in your post...If you need to make it more flexible than Pandas styling provides, you can save it as HTML and then format that downstream, see here. Or use some of the CSS styling options I use there to try to combine with Bhargav's code.

Note: this table is not directly printable in a console or terminal or IDE. you should use Jupyter notebook...
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'planet': ['Earth', 'Moon', 'Mars'], 'mass_to_earth': [1, 0.606, 0.107]})
df_styled = df.style.set_table_styles(
    [

        {'selector': 'table', 'props': [('border-collapse', 'collapse')]},
        {'selector': 'th', 'props': [('border', '3px solid black'), ('font-weight', 'bold')]},
        {'selector': 'td', 'props': [('border', '1px solid black')]},
        {'selector': 'td, th', 'props': [('padding', '8px')]}
    ]
)

df_styled

If you want to see the output if you don't have Jupyter notebook installed then use .to_html
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'planet': ['Earth', 'Moon', 'Mars'], 'mass_to_earth': [1, 0.606, 0.107]})
df_styled = df.style.set_table_styles(
    [

        {'selector': 'table', 'props': [('border-collapse', 'collapse')]},
        {'selector': 'th', 'props': [('border', '3px solid black'), ('font-weight', 'bold')]},
        {'selector': 'td', 'props': [('border', '1px solid black')]},
        {'selector': 'td, th', 'props': [('padding', '8px')]}
    ]
)

df_styled.to_html("styled_table.html")

styled_table.html

Let me know if you looking same output? Little bit confused with the question..
